# How do I install language packs on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server, language-pack

Tried downloading the x64 version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=03831393-EEF7-48A5-A69F-0CE72B883DF2). The setup doesn't even run. Just terminates without any error or anything (silently).

Tried downloading the iso with 35 languages [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/D/A/3DA3C28F-94E1-44E8-9816-293161322EAD/7600.16385.090713-1255_x64fre_server_langpacks_1-GRMSXLP1_DVD.iso). (Link from the bottom of first page).
Mounted iso, windows finds the languages in the control panel applet, but says: The language cannot be installed on this computer.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you download the 2008 R2 SP1 Multilingual package, and not the 2008 R2 Multilingual package:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12250

Comment: This was the solution to our problem. Installer did not even start, your solution helped.